# Metropolis Hastings algorithm for joint posterior of probability of heads for 2 coins

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, posterior, metropolis-hastings

I am trying to implement a simple metropolis hastings algorithm to simulate the joint posterior of the probability of flipping heads for 2 coins, $\theta_1,\theta_2$. I am following the problem statement outlined in this tutorial by [Patrick Ford](https://www.casact.org/library/studynotes/MASII_mcmc_algorithms_v0.5.pdf).

I am not able to get why the algorithm keeps getting values that exceed the range of 0 < $\theta$ < 1. The metropolis Hastings algorithm should reject samples that are far away from the true posterior probability and accept samples that are closer to the true posterior.

This is the code that I have for the simple problem. Am I calculating the unnormalized posterior wrongly or something ?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import beta
import math


# parameters, lets say theta_1 is unbiased and prior to our data we observed 5 heads and 6 tails.
theta_1 = beta(5,6)

# lets say theta_2 is biased. Prior to our data we observed 10 heads and 4 tails
theta_2 = beta(10,4)

# for theta_1, the data we obtain is 10 heads and 10 tails 
# for theta_2, the data we obtain is 15 heads and 6 tails

# start metropolis hastings. Posterior can be computed analytically as well.

def nCr(n,r):
    f = math.factorial
    return f(n) / f(r) / f(n-r)

def log_likeilihood(theta, trials, heads):
    likelihood = nCr(trials, heads) * (theta**heads) * (1 - theta) ** (trials - heads)
    return np.log(likelihood)

def log_prior(prior, theta):
    return np.log(prior.pdf(theta))

def compute_acceptance_prob(theta_curr, theta_prop):
    # likelihood * prior. Compute the log unnormalized posterior
    # logPost = logLLH + logPrior
    theta_curr_1 = theta_curr[0]
    theta_curr_2 = theta_curr[1]
    
    theta_prop_1 = theta_prop[0]
    theta_prop_2 = theta_prop[1]
    
#     print(theta_prop_1)
#     print(theta_prop_2)
#     print(theta_curr_1)
#     print(theta_curr_2)
    
    log_likelihood_theta_curr_1 = log_likeilihood(theta_curr_1, 20, 10) # 20 trials, 10 heads
    log_likelihood_theta_curr_2 = log_likeilihood(theta_curr_2, 21, 15) # 21 trials, 15 heads
    
    log_likelihood_theta_prop_1 = log_likeilihood(theta_prop_1, 20, 10) # 20 trials, 10 heads
    log_likelihood_theta_prop_2 = log_likeilihood(theta_prop_2, 21, 15) # 21 trials, 15 heads
    
    log_prior_curr_1 = log_prior(theta_1, theta_curr_1)
    log_prior_curr_2 = log_prior(theta_2, theta_curr_2)
    
    log_prior_prop_1 = log_prior(theta_1, theta_prop_1)
    log_prior_prop_2 = log_prior(theta_2, theta_prop_2)
    
    joint_likelihood_curr = log_likelihood_theta_curr_1 + log_likelihood_theta_curr_2
    joint_likelihood_prop = log_likelihood_theta_prop_1 + log_likelihood_theta_prop_2
    
    log_post_curr = joint_likelihood_curr + log_prior_curr_1 + log_prior_curr_2
    log_post_prop = joint_likelihood_prop + log_prior_prop_1 + log_prior_prop_2
    
    return min(1,log_post_prop / log_post_curr)

theta_curr = np.array([np.random.beta(5,6), np.random.beta(10,4)]) # sample from beta 
print(theta_curr)
MAX_ITERS = 10000
prop_mean = [0,0]
prop_cov = [[0.005,0],[0,0.005]]
thetas = []
for i in range(MAX_ITERS):
    # sample from gaussian proposal 
    #print(np.random.multivariate_normal(prop_mean, prop_cov))
    theta_prop = theta_curr + np.random.multivariate_normal(prop_mean, prop_cov)
    print(theta_prop)
    # evaluate unnormalized posterior
    prob = compute_acceptance_prob(theta_curr, theta_prop)
    r = np.random.uniform(0,1)
    # evaluate unnormalized posterior
    thetas.append(theta_curr)
    if prob > r:
        theta_curr = theta_prop
```

Have been thinking about it for awhile now. Alot of the samples from the posterior are $< 0 $ and $>1$, which Im not sure why.

**EDIT**

$$p(D_1,D_2|\theta_1,\theta_2) = p(D_1|\theta_1)*p(D_2|\theta_2)$$
Therefore the joint log likelihood is $log\, p(D_1|\theta_1) + log \,p(D_2|\theta_2)$ as what I have computed.

**EDIT**
I realised that there is a mistake in computing the acceptance ratio. I should not have used the unnormalised log ratio in the computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Binomial likelihood function$$\ell(\theta)={n \choose x}\theta^x(1-\theta)^{n-x}$$is only defined when $0\le\theta\le 1$. Computing $\ell(1.4)$ or $\ell(-2.3)$ makes no sense as there is no Binomial experiment with a probability of $1.4$ or $-2.3$. For a parameter value outside the possible parameter range $(0,1)$, **the likelihood need be set to zero.**

The [referenced tutorial](https://www.casact.org/library/studynotes/MASII_mcmc_algorithms_v0.5.pdf) has this safety step:

```
# If any of the values in thetas_prop is not in [0, 1.0] 
# then replace their value with
# the same element in thetas_curr, otherwise keep their values
thetas_prop <-mapply(FUN =function(x, y)ifelse((x>1|x<0), y, x),
    x = thetas_prop,y = thetas_curr)
```

meaning that the proposed values for $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are always in the range $(0,1)$. The truncation in the proposal means that the Metropolis-Hastings acceptance ratio as given in the tutorial

```
# Accept/reject logic
p_accept_theta_prop =pmin(posterior_prop/posterior_curr, 1.0)
```

should be checked. Indeed, the proposal density is
$$f(\xi|\theta)=\Phi((0,1)|\theta)\frac{\varphi(\xi-\theta)\mathbb I_{(0,1)}(\xi)}{\Phi((0,1)|\theta)}+\left[1-\Phi((0,1)|\theta)\right]\mathbb I_{\xi=\theta}$$
where $\varphi$ denotes the Normal density and $\Phi$ the Normal cdf. The acceptance ratio is then
$$\dfrac{\pi(\xi|x)}{\pi(\theta|x)}\,\dfrac{f(\theta|\xi)}{f(\xi|\theta)}$$
and symmetry in the proposal leads to justify the ratio as given.

But a perfectly valid and straightforward alternative is to simply set the likelihood to zero when the proposed value is outside the range $(0,1)$. This clearly prevents the Markov chain to move there.

Note on the minor side that this example is somewhat absurd as the two components of $\theta$ are independent a posteriori and the simulated bivariate Markov chain is less efficient than simulated two independent Markov chains.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I thought the chain should favour likelihood’s that are closer to the posterior distribution and hence theta values that are within 0-1 should be favoured over theta values that are >1 or <0? Or is there some undefined behaviour when likelihood’s > 1 and <0 ?

Comment: Also what do you mean by independent a posteriori ?

Comment: See update in the answer. Note that I exclude parameter values outside $(0,1)$, **not likelihood values outside $(0,1)$**.

Comment: When I run the code I get samples that are >1 and <0. Intuitively however shouldn’t those values be more likely to be rejected as they are far away from the true posterior, which lies between 0 - 1?

Comment: We have a communication problem: I am telling you **values outside $(0,1)$ should be rejected 100% of the time, as being impossible, by extending the likelihood function or the prior density to be zero outside $(0,1)$.**

Comment: I understand thank you. Also, I noticed that the way that they are computing the joint likelihood is quite different from the way i do it ? in the R code they are computing the unnormalized posterior separately for theta_1 and theta_2, just like in the 1D case, and they are accepting either one values in theta_prop vector but can reject the other. On the other hand, the way I do it is to either accept the whole proposal vector or reject the whole proposal vector. I think this has caused my result to be somewhat wrong as well. Could you explain why my method does not work ?

Comment: I have edited my post to show how I think the joint likelihood should be computed

Comment: Accepting or rejecting both components $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ at once is correct but less efficient since the probability of acceptance is then the square of the univariate one.

Comment: When do we know whether to accept/reject each theta component individually or to accept/reject the whole vector ? For this problem, I can see that the method the tutorial uses is the same as applying a MCMC method twice in each loop, one for theta_1 and another for theta_2.